# In sml, question about scope is ambiguous

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
val x = 2
fun f (z,w) = x + z + w
val z = 3
val x = 4
val ans = f(z,x)
```

why the value of ans is 9?
In f, I think the x value is noted as 2 since the val x is declared and the x is not declared when it comes to fun f(z,w)
Am i right??

Answer (score 2):

Your way of phrasing the question suggests that you are thinking in terms of *variables*. SML doesn't really have variables in the same way that a language like Java has variables. It has *values* which can be *named*. In `val x = 2` the value `2` is bound to the name `x`. At that point, there is no real distinction between `x` and `2`. This is because SML is a functional language which enforces [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) where in any expression a variable can be replaced by its value without changing the meaning of the expression. Thus in

```
fun f (z,w) = x + z + w
```

the `x` can be replaced by `2` without changing the meaning of the expression. Hence this definition is equivalent to

```
fun f (z,w) = 2 + z + w
```

Later on, your code creates a new value 4 and (legally, although somewhat inconsistently) names that new value `x` as well. This creates a completely new binding. You haven't *changed* `x` -- you destroyed (or at least permanently shadowed) the old `x` and created a new one. This new `x` is what is used in the final function invocation. The values of `x,z` are at that point in the code `4,3` respectively, hence by referential transparency

```
f(z,w) = f(3,4) = 2 + 3 + 4 = 9
```

Comment: I would say *shadowed* rather than *destroyed* since `f` still refers to it. Destroying sounds like the value is physically inaccessible when it is only the name of the old `x` that is onwards inaccessible.

Comment: @SimonShine Exactly what happens depends on the compiler internals. A relatively simple optimization for `f` would be to replace `x` by the literal 2. I assumed that this was the case. In any event, when I used the word destroyed, I was thinking of the binding of `x` to `2` rather than that instance of the value `2` since that binding no longer exists in that environment. I'll change the wording to be more cautious.